# Juju and MAAS: ERROR No matching node is available

Tags: juju, maas

I had created an environment w/ juju + MAAS, then destroyed it due to some misconfiguration. But then I re-commissioned a node (MAAS is showing the node as deployed) and now when I run `juju -v bootstrap` I get the following:

```
sysadmin@myst-a-2:~$ juju -v bootstrap
2013-05-01 11:52:02,275 DEBUG Initializing juju bootstrap runtime
2013-05-01 11:52:02,308 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'maas' (origin: distro type: maas)...
2013-05-01 11:52:02,334 DEBUG Verifying writable storage
2013-05-01 11:52:02,368 DEBUG Launching juju bootstrap instance.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 422, in errback
    self._startRunCallbacks(fail)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 489, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 576, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1127, in gotResult
    _inlineCallbacks(r, g, deferred)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1069, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/control/bootstrap.py", line 39, in command
    yield provider.bootstrap(constraints)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1069, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/providers/common/bootstrap.py", line 57, in _launch_machine
    {"machine-id": "0", "constraints": self._constraints}, master=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1069, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/providers/common/launch.py", line 64, in run
    machines = yield self.start_machine(machine_id, zookeepers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1069, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/providers/maas/launch.py", line 40, in start_machine
    instance_data = yield maas_client.acquire_node(self._constraints)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 576, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/providers/maas/maas.py", line 95, in _process_error
    raise ProviderError(error.response)
juju.errors.ProviderError: No matching node is available.
2013-05-01 11:52:02,444 ERROR Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 422, in errback
    self._startRunCallbacks(fail)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 489, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 576, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1127, in gotResult
    _inlineCallbacks(r, g, deferred)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1069, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/control/bootstrap.py", line 39, in command
    yield provider.bootstrap(constraints)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1069, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/providers/common/bootstrap.py", line 57, in _launch_machine
    {"machine-id": "0", "constraints": self._constraints}, master=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1069, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/providers/common/launch.py", line 64, in run
    machines = yield self.start_machine(machine_id, zookeepers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1069, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/providers/maas/launch.py", line 40, in start_machine
    instance_data = yield maas_client.acquire_node(self._constraints)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 576, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/providers/maas/maas.py", line 95, in _process_error
    raise ProviderError(error.response)
juju.errors.ProviderError: No matching node is available.

2013-05-01 11:52:02,444 ERROR No matching node is available.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me obvious that you are missing nodes capable of beeing bootstrapped. Do you have any MAAS nodes in Ready state? If there is only nodes deployed and no one in ready state, you can not bootstrap.. You need at least one node in ready state...